# Getting Data from database and showing it in alert

Tags: ajax, laravel

I'm new to laravel and I want to get data from database and show it on Alert using ajax

My Route:

```
Route::get('getforajax/{id}','Home@getforajax');
```

My Controller:

```
    public function getforajax ($id)
{
    $result=DB::select('select * from employees where empid =?',[$id]);
    return $result;
}
```

my View:

```
            $('#empid1').keyup(function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'getforajax/3',
                type: 'GET',
                data: data,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data.empid);
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: Whats your problem

Comment: on alert message it shows [Undifined]

Comment: @eraufi: What result get from ```$result``` variable in controller ?

Comment: did you use DB;?

Comment: My Route and Controller shows data in [{"id":2,"empid":3"}]

Comment: What's data you provide in ajax call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return json from the controller.

```
return response()->json($result, 200);
```

However, the result will be an array of al the resultant rows from the query. So even if you are expecting a single result from query, it is still going to give yo an array of single entry.

```
[
  [
    id => something,
    name => something
  ]
]
```

Also, you can improve it as following :

In your javacript you need to do :

```
data[0].empId
```

However, you need to make sure the data is there. Use eloquent models for loading entry from Id :

```
$result = Employee::findOrFail($employeeid);
```

And then you do directly do :

```
alert(data.empid);
```

Comment: still same problem

Comment: Updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should try this:

```
use App\Employee; //employee table's model

public function getforajax ($id)
{
    $result=Employee::find($id);
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: I think `response()->json($result, 200);` is standard.

Comment: It' bring data based on id could you please modity it so it can bring based on empid Thanks